# BES 5.0 SSL Certificate

Tags: ssl, certificate, blackberry, bes

I have recently installed BES 5.0 on a Hyper-V (i know it's not officially supported) 64-bit Server 2008 box with a remote SQL 2005 database.  I successfully installed and was able to access the Blackberry Administration Service but was getting untrusted certificate errors so I followed the documentation for importing CA and BAS certificates with the Java keytool.  They imported successfully but now the BAS webpage shows a "page cannot be displayed" error.  TSupport is no help at all.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Resolved.  In the registry, browse to:  HKEY_Current_User\Software\Research In Motion\Blackberry Enterprise Server\Administration Service\Key Store.  Ensure that you have the following two keys with your keystore password as the value:

CacertsKeyStorePass
WebkeyStorePass  <----this is the one i was missing.